# Frusturatingly simple looking problem from Undergrad Real Analysis Course

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $\mathit f$: $\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ be a function defined by $$ \mathit f(x):= 2x+\sin x$$
Show that the equation : $\mathit f(x)=n$, (Where n $\in \Bbb N $) admits a unique real solution, denoted $\mathit x_n$. What is $x_0$?

This is a problem from my real analysis homework, the first in a four part problem. I pursued the usual "let's just set the equation equal to n and see if something falls out" approach, which failed. This is being done within the context of a chapter on the intermediate value theorem and the mean value theorem.

Comment: We need some context here.  If you find the problem frustrating, you must have tried something, so tell us what failed.  Otherwise, we're not just going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Isn.t it obvious? The function is continuous and the derivative is strictly positive for all $x$ and the range is $(-\infty,+\infty)$, so $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Some context added.

Comment: Have you tried using the intermediate value theorem or mean value theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's a Rolle's Theorem (Mean Value Theorem) problem.  Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = n$ for some $n$ and two different values of $x_1$ and $x_2.$   Then Rolle's Theorem (or the MVT) says there is a point between $x_1$ and $x_2$ where the derivative is zero.  You can get a contradiction from that.

Comment: You've shown the solution is unique if it exists, but you didn't show it exists.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to compute the derivative of $f$ to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you very much with another way.